# Group's "emailPermission" in Directory API in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm using Google Apps Provisioning API with gdata-java-client to manage Google Apps domain. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/

Since Provisioning API is deprecated now, I'm considering to migrate to new Google Apps Directory API with google-api-java-client. Looks like the most of functionalities of my software can be migrated, but I couldn't find how to set "emailPermission" of the group settings. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_group

It sounds like Google Apps Groups Settings API would be it, but it has far more high-functioning than Provisioning API do and I don't think these are equivalent.

Is there any equivalent API for Directory API/Admin SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Admin SDK Directory API, service-specific settings/attributes were left to service-specific APIs, thus the Group Settings API is the correct method to set group settings.

To get an idea of how the Group Settings map to the old provisioning API group permissions, try creating a group with the provisioning API for each of the permissions, then use the Group Settings API to GET that group's settings and you'll have a map of the settings each of the old permissions defaulted to.